# Sql Server 2014 update path advice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-pack

I recently inherited a SQL Server 2014 installation and I'd like to install updates. The virtual machine runs Windows Server 2016 standard. The server has about 50+ databases with 400Gb of data. I'm a developer and don't have much DBA knowledge.

Current plan is to update SQL Server to 2014 SP3 (right now it's RTM). Are there any problems I should be aware of?

I do plan on trying it out on a non-production server first - but unfortunately can't get the same exact Windows version.

Is there some script or utility to healthcheck SQL Server installation? I doubt that manually running sql statements will be very thorough. I only found [Brent Ozar's blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) so far.

Comment: Hi @Chester89--in general, upgrading to a service pack is safe.  There's no way someone will tell you it's 100% safe because we can't test it with your application.  It's highly unlikely there will be an issue, but impossible for anyone to state that as a fact.  The best approach is to have a test environment to test it.  If you don't have that, then get good backups and then upgrade.  As for the healthcheck script--this site is not a forum for recommending software.  There are tons of SQL Server monitoring applications out there.  Most have evals--check them out and see what you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want to keep up to date on service packs in SQL < 2014 as you won't get support after awhile if you don't.

The support policy can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17138/service-pack-lifecycle-policy).

Generally installing Service Packs is safe but for any production system please make sure you have a strong backup model in place and hopefully a test environment to simulate all changes for production ahead of time to validate that they work.

Comment: are backups backwards compatible? e.g. if I take a backup from instance with SP3 installed, will I be able to restore it to RTM instance? I see some answers that suggest it won't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version

Comment: within a major version, you can restore a database to the RTM version.  2008 and 2008 R2 were different releases despite the naming.  Going from <service release X of major release Y> to RTM version of major release Y should work fine.